# Behaviour of roots of family of polynomials

Tags: number-theory, analysis, polynomials, roots

Let 
$$
P(x)=(1+\frac{w^3}{12})x^4 + w^2 \sqrt{u}x^3+(wu-\frac{2}{u}(1+\frac{w^3}{12}) )x^2-\frac{w^2}{\sqrt{u}}x+\frac{1}{u^2}(1+\frac{w^3}{12}) 
$$ 
a polynomial in the variable $x$, where $w,u>0$. If $w$ is fixed, How I can study the behaviour of the roots in the cases when $u\to 0$ and $u\to \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the obviously related terms to get
$$
P(x)=\left(1+\frac{w^3}{12}\right)\left(x^2-\frac1u\right)^2+w\sqrt{u}x\left(wx^2+\sqrt{u}x-\frac{w}{u}\right)
$$
With $y=x-\frac1{xu}$ and for $xu\ne 0$ the equation $P(x)=0$ is equivalent to
$$
0=Q(y)=\left(1+\frac{w^3}{12}\right)y^2+w^2\sqrt{u}y+wu
$$
This means that you can actually compute the roots via a nested sequence of two quadratic equations.

Comment: Dear LUtzL:
How can I prove that if $w> \sqrt[3]{6}$ then the roots of $P(x)$ are always reals?

Comment: You need to ensure that the discriminant $w^4u-4wu(1+\frac1{12}w^3)$ of the second quadratic is positive, that is $3w^3-12-w^3\ge 0$. The solutions $x$ of the first quadratic are real as long as $y$ is real.

Comment: And the last question: How can I prove that if $x$ is a root of the polynomial, then for all $u>0$, $Re(x^2)<1/u$ ?
I try to prove this using your auxiliary polynomial but I can't obtain anything.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $u = U^2$, then the question is about finding the Puiseux series solution for a polynomial equation. If we draw the Newton polygon, we can see that the terms corresponding to the small $U$ and large $x$ expansion are
$$v U^4 x^4 - 2 v U^2 x^2 + v, \\
x_{1, 2} \sim -\frac 1 U, \; x_{3, 4} \sim \frac 1 U,
\quad U \to 0,$$
where $v = w^3 + 12$. The terms corresponding to large $U$ and small $x$ are
$$12 w U^6 x^2 - 12 w^2 U^3 x + v, \\
x_{1, 2} \sim \frac {3 w^2 \pm \sqrt D} {6 w U^3},
\quad U \to \infty,$$
$D = 6 w (w^3 - 6)$. Large $U$ and large $x$ gives
$$v U^4 x^4 + 12 w^2 U^5 x^3 + 12 w U^6 x^2, \\
x_{3, 4} \sim \frac {2 (-3 w^2 \pm \sqrt D) U} v,
\quad U \to \infty.$$

Comment: Dear Maxim, thanks for your answer!
Where I can find material for read about Puiseux series and understand your solution ?

Comment: See Sendra, Winkler, Perez-Diaz, *Rational Algebraic Curves: A Computer Algebra Approach*, Ch. 2.5.

Comment: Dear Maxim, a question, please.
By reading the reference you suggested, I was able to make the calculations and obtained the same polygon, and the same polynomials for the cases when: $U$ is small and $x$ is long, $U$ long and $x$ small, and, $U$ long with $x$ long, but: Why do these polynomials deliver that information? I don't understand it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: From the viewpoint of the method of dominant balance, you can say that the terms $U^0 x^0, \, U^2 x^2, \, U^3 x$ are dominated by one of the terms $U^4 x^4, \, U^5 x^3, \, U^6 x^2$ when both $U$ and $x$ are large, no matter what the relation between $U$ and $x$ is, and similarly for other cases.

Comment: Why in the case when to large  and small , only two roots appear if it is a polynomial of degree 4?

Comment: Which polynomial do you mean? The large $U$/small $x$ case gives a quadratic in $x$. In the third case, two roots are zero. The method gives the terms of the expansion iteratively, we take the first approximation, make a change of variables and compute the next terms in the same way. Zero doesn't give us an approximation, we're left with the same equation.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to "clear denominators" to avoid infinities so that you can use the continuity of roots of homogeneous polynomials with respect to the coefficients.  In particular, let us assume that $1+w^3/12\neq 0$ and consider the roots of $P(x)$ when $u$ is close to but not equal to $0$.  These are the same as the roots of $$u^2P(x)=u^2vx^4 + w^2u^{5/2}x^3+(wu^3-2uv)x^2-w^2u^{3/2}x+v$$ where $v=1+w^3/12$.  Now unfortunately, we cannot just directly use the continuity of roots of polynomials of the same degree with respect to the coefficients here, since the leading coefficient $u^2v$ is going to $0$ so the degree decreases in the limit.  The trick is to homogenize: let $x=s/t$ and consider the homogeneous polynomial $$Q(s,t)=t^4u^2P(x)=u^2vs^4+ w^2u^{5/2}s^3t+(wu^3-2uv)s^2t^2-w^2u^{3/2}st^3+vt^4.$$  There is then a theorem that the roots of a nonzero homegeneous polynomial in projective space vary continuously with the coefficients.  So, as $u\to 0$, the roots of $Q(s,t)$ approach the roots of $$vt^4$$ since all the other coefficients have factors of $u$ and thus go to $0$.     But those roots are all just $t=0$, which is the point at $\infty$ in projective space.  In other words, writing $x=s/t$, all the roots for $x$ approach $\infty$ as $u\to 0$.

(In this case, we could see that more directly by just observing that if $x$ is bounded in size and $u$ is very close to $0$, then the final term $\frac{1}{u^2}(1+\frac{w^3}{12})$ will be much larger than all the other terms of $P(x)$ and so $P(x)$ cannot be $0$.  This means that as $u\to 0$, $P(x)$ cannot have any roots inside larger and larger balls, so that the roots must all approach $\infty$.)

Similar analyses can be done for the case where $1+w^3/12=0$ or $u\to\infty$, to find that some of the roots approach $\infty$ and others approach $0$, depending on which coefficient of $P(x)$ grows fastest in the limit (and thus survives in the limit after we clear denominators so that the others go to $0$).

Comment: Dear Eric, thanks for your answer !
I have two question about your comment:
1.- In which reference can I find the theorem about projective spaces that you mentioned?
2.- What would the case analysis be like when $u \to \infty$ ?, This is not very clear to me.